# arraylist with object type

Tags: c#, linq, arraylist

hi i using arraylist and storing simple object array in that , my sample code snipt

```
  ArrayList rows = new ArrayList();

        object[] objs = new object[3];

        objs[0] = 1;
        objs[1] = "dilip";
        objs[2] = 27;
        rows.Add(objs);

        objs = new object[3];

        objs[0] = 2;
        objs[1] = "lucky";
        objs[2] = 42;
        rows.Add(objs);

        objs = new object[3];
        objs[0] = 3;
        objs[1] = "user";
        objs[2] = 46;
        rows.Add(objs);
        objs = new object[3];
        objs[0] = 4;
        objs[1] = "testing";
        objs[2] = 76;
        rows.Add(objs);
        objs = new object[3];
        objs[0] = 5;
        objs[1] = "trying";
        objs[2] = 44;
       rows.Add(objs);
```

How can i apply asc or desc sorting on any index of object 
for example sorting based on name which index 1 or sorting based on age which index 2 ..

please provide any suggestion .
Thanks ..

Comment: Why would someone use non-generic `ArrayList` of non-typed `object[]`. It makes your code difficult, unreadable and error-prone with different issues starting from `InvalidCastExceptions` to boxing / unboxing performance overhead. Use typed array of structs instead.

Comment: i know , but its existing project and new joiner so cant propose design changes . with existing design there is any way ? thanks

Comment: @Dilip take a look at answer using `List<object[]>` is there a reason why you cannot use it instead of `ArrayList`?

Comment: @Svek - reason is i m new in this company so cant ask them to change there design or  but anyway i will discuss with them and will change to list later on  . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have comparer to sort your ArrayList type. In your case it would look something like this:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer
{
    int IComparer.Compare(Object x, Object y)
    {
        int sortingIndex = 1;

        var xUnbox = x as object[];
        var yUnbox = y as object[];

        return ((new CaseInsensitiveComparer()).Compare(yUnbox[sortingIndex], xUnbox[sortingIndex]));
    }
}
```

Having this, you can now sort your ArrayList:

```
var comparer = new MyComparer();
rows.Sort(comparer);

foreach (object[] line in rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line[1]);
}
```

This example would sort your ArrayList by index 1.

Although I would highly recommend using strongly typed collection, like `List<YourType>` instead, since then you could just Linq order that.

Answer (score 1):

Most of LINQ methods will work with a strongly typed `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

Use `OfType` method like this `rows.OfType<object[]>().OrderBy(x => x[1])`

Though the way you approach your data structures will quickly make the code unmaintainable. You'd better consider using classes to reflect your data.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you could not use `List<object[]>` instead of using `ArrayList`?

For example:

```
List<object[]> rows = new List<object[]>();

object[] objs = new object[3];

objs[0] = 1;
objs[1] = "dilip";
objs[2] = 27;
rows.Add(objs);

var query = rows.Where(r => (string)r[1] == "dilip");
```

You could then do all your various sorting, etc.

```
var query = rows
    .OrderBy(r => (int)r[0])
    .OrderBy(r => (string)r[1])
    .OrderByDescending(r => (int)r[2]);
```